# Image turns to black and white after downloading

Tags: photos, pictures

[image: Original image]

Here's the image. Clearly's got a blue tint. But when I download it, it's all just black and white.

[image: Image as downloaded]

Any idea why?

Comment: What program are you using to view the downloaded picture? Have you tried dropping the file into a web browser? I'm guessing your image viewer does not understand the embedded "color profile".

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess your machine's colour calibration is out.

The picture is essentially black & white. Though technically CMYK rather than Greyscale, a quick analysis shows no distinct colour-cast at all, merely minor variations across the image - possibly caused by the jpg compression itself, or very small inaccuracies in the original scan.

This is the same picture, converted to actual Greyscale. I see it as perceptually darker overall, but no change in colour-cast.

[image]

<sup>The perceptual darker image here reminds me I need to recalibrate my system… hasn\'t been done for a while… :)</sup>

Comment: So you're saying, it being slightly blue here is an artifact?

[img](http://f1.bcbits.com/img/0005515064_0.jpg)

Comment: Do you see either of the images on this page as slightly blue? If so, which? Colour calibration for workflow is too big a subject to cover on Super User, it would be more suited to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: In my image viewer it looks all grey. To answer @grawity questions I tried JpegView and Photoshop. But the first one looks blue in Firefox and Opera and when I converted it to png via online image editor, it shows as blue everywhere http://i.imgsafe.org/c61786b.png

Comment: It's definitely [bluer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PqRYD.png) in GThumb than GIMP. (Though toggling "Apply the color profile" does nothing, so I'm probably wrong about ICC profiles affecting this. Could be the other metadata like "Media White Point" though?)

Comment: I see it blue using Chrome, but not in Safari. Importing from Chrome to pshop it goes back to being 'correct'. Some browsers aren't reading the profiles correctly, then, as @grawity guessed. Quick screen-grab from Chrome… http://i.stack.imgur.com/BAvn2.png

Comment: Assuming the grey one is the true representation, why doesn't black color look black on it, but slightly brightened, i.e. gray? The blue-ish representation however, shows the black parts as actually black. I'm referring to the three horizontal lines by the way.

Comment: Because [& again we're getting too far off-topic for SU & this really should be on graphics] in CMYK, C0 M0 Y0 K100 does not equal RGB 0,0,0 but only [approximately] 30,30,30. This is because you cannot get enough ink on a page in one pass to make black truly black. The usual trick on a press would be to add cyan to it, making it perceptually darker without you really being able to see there was any blueness to it at all. The closest to 'true' black on a press is about C70 M70 Y70 K90… but in practise, you'd be pulling ink back off the paper trying to get that much down.

Comment: So why if there is no black in the original representation, does it become black when converted to [png](http://i.imgsafe.org/c61786b.png) via http://online-image-editor.com? And why does gray get blue?

Comment: Those bars are 100% black, no other colour. Anything else you may see is a mis-reading of the colour profile.

Comment: even on your [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BAvn2.png), the bars look brighter on the second screenshot, not completely black. and what about the part where gray becomes blue?

Comment: Yes, as I said, chrome is mis-reading the profiles - or ignoring them altogether.

Comment: Well JPEGView and Photoshop also show black as gray in case of that image. So is there even a viewer that is capable of displaying that image correctly? BTW I realize that is a ton of questions, sorry.

Comment: Safari works for me. No idea what there might be for Windows, though.